# Import Range Dynamically Based On Size

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I'm trying to combine two Google Sheets together using query. For example:

```
=query({'Sheet 1'!A1:D50;'Sheet 2'!A1:D500})
```

However, the cell range that I would like to combine changes.

I've created a function that counts the rows in A.

```
=countif(A1:A,"<>")
```

Let's say it equals 26.

I then only want to import the range A1:D26.

Is there any way to easily do this?

I've tried

```
=query({'Sheet 1'!A1:("D"&countif('Sheet 1'!A1));'Sheet 2'!A1:D500})
```

Is this something that `OFFSET` could be used for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to leave endrow empty:

```
=QUERY({'Sheet 1'!A1:D; 'Sheet 2'!A1:D})
```

and to remove empty rows:

```
=QUERY({'Sheet 1'!A1:D; 'Sheet 2'!A1:D}, "where Col1 is not null")
```

Comment: I want to be able to change the import range of Sheet 1 and Sheet 2 based on how many rows they have. Ie. Countif('Sheet 1'!A1:A, "<>"),Countif('Sheet 2'!A1:A, "<>")

Comment: So it may be =query({'Sheet 1'!A1:D50;'Sheet 2'!A1:D500}) or =query({'Sheet 1'!A1:D400;'Sheet 2'!A1:D15}) depending on how many rows are in each sheet